# Отправить письмо из php с html-частью и вложенным файлом

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Подскажите как исправить ошибку. В письме приходит текст со знаками вопросами.

```
$to2 = $user_email;
    $from = 'pochta@mail.ru';

    $subject2 = 'Автоответ';

    $message = "Автоматическое письмо\n";

    $filename = "Anketa_2015.docx"; //Имя файла для прикрепления

    $boundary = "---"; //Разделитель
    /* Заголовки */
    $headers2 = "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n";
    $headers2 .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";
    $body = "--$boundary\n";
    /* Присоединяем текстовое сообщение */
    $body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printablenn";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    //$body .= $message."\n";
    $body .= $message;
    $body .= "--$boundary\n";
    $file = fopen($filename, "r"); //Открываем файл
    $text = fread($file, filesize($filename)); //Считываем весь файл
    fclose($file); //Закрываем файл
    /* Добавляем тип содержимого, кодируем текст файла и добавляем в тело письма */
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\n\n";
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($text))."\n";
    $body .= "--".$boundary ."--\n";



    mail($to2, $subject2, $body, $headers2);
```

Comment: *Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printablenn* — не закралась ли здесь опечатка? вместо `nn`, по идее, должно быть `\n`.

Comment: @alexander barakin тогда вообще пустота приходит

Comment: кстати, разделитель (в переменной `$boundary`) `---` — это вообще-то плохая идея. используйте лучше какую-нибудь случайную строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно, налучшим решением будет использовать уже написанный класс.

например, [php_LibMail](http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html) или [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

но если хочется «самому, своими руками», то вот вполне рабочий (хотя и далёкий от идеала) вариант. приспосабливайте под свои нужды:

```
$to = "a@b.c";
$from = "d@e.f";
$subject = "тестовое письмо";
$message = "<html><body>пишет автомат</body></html>";
$filename = "важный.док";

$subj = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
$boundary = uniqid('np');
$nl = "\n";

$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$blob = fread($file, filesize($filename));
fclose($file);

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $nl;
$headers .= "From: " . $from . $nl . "Reply-To: " . $from . $nl;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=" . $boundary . $nl;

$msg = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 
$msg .= $nl . $nl . "--" . $boundary . $nl;
$msg .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8" . $nl . $nl;
$msg .= $message;
$msg .= $nl . $nl . "--" . $boundary . $nl;
$msg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" . $nl;
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $nl;
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; " .
 "filename=\"=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($filename)."?=\"" . $nl . $nl;
$msg .= chunk_split(base64_encode($blob)) . $nl;
$msg .= $nl . $nl . "--" . $boundary . "--";

mail($to, $subj, $msg, $headers);
```

Comment: Даже не отправляет ничего.

Comment: так замените значения `$to`, `$from` и `$filename`  на реальные адреса и имя файла.

Comment: Я ж не настолько тупой))) Заменил конечно. Может у меня на хостинге mail не работает. Сейчас  проверю на другом и отпишу.

Comment: Работает! Спасибище большущее добрый человек. Это у меня хостинг такой тормоз (smartape.ru)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, использовать кодировку utf-8.

Comment: Файл в кодировке UTF-8 и прописано в нём utf-8 тоже, разве не видно?

Comment: @Владимир, по какому признаку надо было угадать, что файл действительно в UTF8?

Comment: я думал Вы про то как прописано в файле.

Comment: @Владимир, что для письма указывается utf-8, я видел. Поэтому и сказал, что надо, чтобы скрипт тоже работал в utf8.

Comment: Ну, в общем не работает.